# Installing in a sub-folder of Angular

Tags: 8, iis

I have an Angular 2+ application running. I would like to install Drupal in a subfolder and have my Angular application to iframe the contents.

Ideal Folder Structure:

```
/             - Angular  
/content      - Drupal
```

I have an existing rewrite rule to rewrite all URLs to index.html. Drupal works fine with pages like http://myapp.com/content/admin, but if I am accessing a page like http://myapp.com/en/page, it will be redirected to the index.html file of the Angular application.

How do I configure Drupal to make it add /content to its URLs?

I am hosting them on IIS. These are the rewrite rules I have now.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="HTTPS Redirection" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Or expose JSON endpoints and write Angular services to fetch the data?

Comment: We have thought of that before, but we would like to let our marketing team to manage the contents of those pages, that is why we came to this direction. I will try to remove the clean URL and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, the following are the changes I've made. I am writing this here in case anyone faces the same problem.

1. I noticed there was another `web.config` file **in root of Drupal folder** (`/content`) and it contains a few rewrite rules.
   I've changed the last rewrite rule which rewrite all requests to `index.php`, it now looks like this:

```xml
<!-- Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to index.php. -->
<rule name="Short URLS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/content/index.php" /> <!-- CHANGES IN THIS LINE, ADDED '/content'/ in front of index.php -->
</rule>
```

2. Modified `.htaccess` file in root of Drupal folder and added this line `RewriteBase /content`, below this line `# RewriteBase /`
3. Modified the `web.config` file in **root folder of Angular App** (`/`) to the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- Install IIS url rewrite module. -->
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/content/(.*)$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```